# Is there a way to link to a specific part of a YouTube video in Android?

Tags: android, youtube

What is the easy way to do it in website,
`http://youtubetime.com/`

But in android i got an error on the folowing code

```
 String video_id="6ZI123IWB2Q"&t=3m37s";        
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, (Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://" + video_id)));
 startActivity(intent);
```

Maybe where is some other way to do so?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video_id)));